Configuring Hibernate with a New Database Schema in Spring Web Flow
I'm currently working on a project that uses Hibernate with Spring Web Flow, and I've encountered a challenge. We need to integrate a new database schema, let's called it "database_schema_test". My goal is to ensure that Hibernate recognizes and maps entities to this new schema correctly.
Here are some details about our current setup:
-Hibernate Configuration: We are using hibernate.cfg.xml to configure Hibernate. The current configuration includes details for our main data source and mappings for existing entities.
-Spring Web Flow: Our application is built using Spring Web Flow, which adds another layer of complexity to our configuration.
What I've Tried:
-Adding the hibernate.default_schema property in hibernate.cfg.xml to specify the new schema.
Issues:
I am unsure how to add a new database schema to hibernate, and I don't know if I have configured everything correctly. I want to ensure that all new entities are mapped to the new schema and that existing configurations are not disrupted.
Has anyone here dealt with a similar situation? Any insights or suggestions on how to properly configure Hibernate to work with a new database schema in a Spring Web Flow application would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
